# Compare a log file of file paths to a directory structure and remove files not in log file

Tags: performance, powershell, compare, large-files

I have a file transfer/sync job that is copying files from the main network into a totally secure network using a custom protocol (ie no SMB). The problem is that because I can't look back to see what files exist, the destination is filling up, as the copy doesn't remove any files it hasn't touched (like robocopy MIR does).

Initailly I wrote a script that:
1. Opens the log file and grabs the file paths out (this is quite quick and painless)
2. Does a Get-ChildItem on the destination folder (now using dir /s /b as it's way faster than gci)
3. Compared the two, and then removed the differences.

The problem is that there are more jobs that require this clean up but the log files are 100MB and the folders contain 600,000 files, so it's taking ages and using tons of memory. I actually have yet to see one finish. I'd really like some ideas on how to make this faster (memory/cpu use doesn't bother me too much but speed is essential.

$destinationMatch = "//server/fileshare/folder/"

the log file contains some headers and footers and then 600,000 lines like this one:

"//server/fileshare/folder/dummy/deep/tags/20140826/more_stuff/Deeper/2012-07-02_2_0.dat_v2" 33296B 0B completed

Here's the script:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$logName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$destinationMatch
)

$logPath = [string]("C:\Logs\" + $logName)
$manifestFile = gci -Path $logPath | where {$_.name -match "manifest"} | sort creationtime -descending | select Name -first 1
$manifestFileName = [string]$manifestFile.name
$manifestFullPath = $logPath + "\" + $manifestFileName

$copiedList = @()
(gc $manifestFullPath -ReadCount 0) | where {$_.trim() -match $DestinationMatch} | % {
    if ( $_ -cmatch '(?<=")[^"]*(?=")' ){
        $copiedList += ($matches[0]).replace("/","\")
    }
}
$dest = $destinationMatch.replace("/","\")
$actualPathString = (gci -Path $dest -Recurse | select fullname).fullnameCompare-Object -ReferenceObject $copiedList -DifferenceObject $actualPathString -PassThru | % {
    $leaf = Split-Path $_ -leaf
    if ($leaf.contains(".")){
        $fsoData = gci -Path $_
        if (!($fsoData.PSIsContainer)){
            Remove-Item $_ -Force
        }
    }
}

$actualDirectory | where {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(gci -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -eq 0} | remove-item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: I am doing my best to wrap my head around your script, but it's almost like you're trying to make things harder for yourself, or you're doing something that I don't understand. This is really just so that you can pass it a file name and path to a log, check if the file is in the log already, and if so delete the file. Right?

Comment: I give up, this makes no sense. You specify a log file, and a destination, but nowhere do I see any reference to the source location. It's like you're looping through the file locations in the log, which are referencing paths at the destination, and if the file doesn't exist, you try to delete that non-existent file at the destination. Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reference the source at all, due to firewall restrictions, so I look at the log file (which is a list of files that should be at the destination) and then try figure out which files shouldn't be there (ie deleted at source).

Comment: Just to clarify, the sync job runs nightly, and the number and size of files is too big to delete the destination folder and just resync nightly, so I need to find a way to remove the files at destination that have been removed at source.

Comment: So couldn't you just pull a directory listing and delete any file not updated within the last 24 hours? Or does your file copy preserve Last Modified date/time?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's assume that your file copy preserves the last modified date/time stamp. If you really need to pull a directory listing, and compare it against a log, I think you're doing a decent job of it. The biggest slow down is obviously going to be pulling your directory listing. I'll address that shortly. For right now I would propose the following modification of your code:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$logName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$destinationMatch
)

$logPath = [string]("C:\Logs\" + $logName)
$manifestFile = gci -Path $logPath | where {$_.name -match "manifest"} | sort creationtime -descending | select -first 1

$RegExPattern = [regex]::escape($DestinationMatch)
$FilteredManifest = gc $manifestfile.FullPath | where {$_ -match "`"($RegexPattern[^`"]*)`""} |%{$matches[1] -replace '/','\'}

$dest = $destinationMatch.replace("/","\")
$DestFileList = gci -Path $dest -Recurse | select Fullname,Attributes
$DestFileList | Where{$FilteredManifest -notcontains $_.FullName -and $_.Attributes -notmatch "Directory"}|Remove-Item $_ -Force
$DestFileList | Where{$FilteredManifest -notcontains $_.FullName -and $_.Attributes -match "Directory" -and (gci -LiteralPath $_ -Recurse -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Length -eq 0}{Remove-Item $_ -Recurse -Force}
```

This stops you from duplicating efforts. There's no need to get your manifest file, and then assign different variables to different properties of the file object, just reference them directly. Then later when you pull your directory listing of the drive (the slow part here), keep the full name and attributes of the files/folders. That way you can easily filter against Attributes to see what's a directory and what not, so we can deal with files first, then clean up directories later after the files are cleaned up.

That script should be a bit more streamlined version of yours. Now, about pulling that directory listing... Here's the deal, using Get-ChildItem is going to be slower than some alternatives (such as dir /s /b) but it stops you from having to duplicate efforts by later checking what's a file, and what's a directory. I suppose if the actual files/folders that you are concerned with are a small percentage of the total, then the double work may actually be worth the time and effort to pull the list with something like `dir /s /b`, and then parse against the log, and only pull folder/file info for the specific items you need to address.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been yanked onto a severe case this week so will test next week and let you know how it goes.